# E:\j2eeproject\Job_Find\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1033: The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

when ever I try to run my project this type of error confuse me please help me.
I'm work in Jsp project but this deployment error I can not solve this I try many
things but is can't work.

E:\j2eeproject\Job_Find\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1033: The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details

Comment: Did you _"See the server log for details"_? What did they say? Please read [ask] to see that "doesn't work" is not a good problem description. If you provide a [mcve], we might have a chance to help you.

Comment: I'm sorry for this
And thankyou for suggestion I'm new in stack overflow

Comment: Being new is not a problem - that's why I'm pointing out the resources we have to support you writing a question that's answerable and valuable for those coming after you, who might get stuck with the same problem. You should read those resources and edit your question with some more information as suggested in those articles.